# what $Hom(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/2)$ is?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, topological-groups

I am calculating the torus cohomology groups with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ coefficients and I get to that $$H^1(T, \mathbb{Z}/2)\cong Hom(H_1(T), \mathbb{Z}/2)=Hom(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/2)$$ but I don't know what P is, could someone please tell me what $Hom(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/2)$ is? Thank you!

Comment: For any $x,y\in \Bbb{Z/2Z}$ then $(n,m) \mapsto nx+my$ is an element of $Hom(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z/2Z})$

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is a coproduct of $\mathbb{Z}$ with itself in the category of Abelian groups, then $Hom(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \simeq Hom(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \times Hom(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \simeq (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler  $Hom(\mathbb{Z}/2, \mathbb{Z}/2)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2$ or $Hom(\mathbb{Z}/2, \mathbb{Z}/2)=0$?

Comment: Nash, do you know the definition of Hom?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
For any $f \in Hom(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/2)$ you have 
$$f(m,n)=mf(1,0)+nf(0,1) \pmod{2}$$

Now, there are four choices for $f(1,0), f(0,1)$ thus this leads to a group of 4 elements. Note also that $f+f=0$ for each $f$.